# Where or how does Sidekiq/Redis store an object when a Job is retrying?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, redis, jobs, sidekiq

We provide our Clients a way to preview mass emails being delivered to their Users. For some of the emails, we mock (`OpenStruct`) some objects and use them in the email view:

*UserMailer*:
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer

```
 def about_to_expire_card_reminder
    ...
    if params[:email_preview]
      @subject += " (email de prueba)"
      @user_default_credit_card = mock_credit_card
    end

    send_email(subject: @subject)
  end
    

  def mock_credit_card
    OpenStruct.new(last_four_digits: "1234 (tarjeta de prueba)",
                   expiration_date: 10.days.from_now.to_date)
  end

end
```

We were forcing errors today and noticed that the `OpenStruct` that `mock_credit_card` returns  does not show up in the `Sidekiq` admin page where the retrying Job shows.

*Retrying Job info:*

```
Next Retry: in 3 minutes
Retry Count: 4
Queue: mailers
Job: ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob
Arguments: "UserMailer", "about_to_expire_card_reminder", "deliver_now", {"params"=>{"user"=>{"_aj_globalid"=>"gid://database/User/1"}, "to"=>info@testemail.com", "email_preview"=>true, "aj_symbol_keys"=>["user,"to","email_preview"]}, "args"=>[],"_aj_symbol_keys"=>["params","args"]}
Error: ActionView::Template:Error: undefined method "last_four_digits" for #struct expiration_date="2021-03-31">
```

Where does `Sidekiq` store the mocked `OpenStruct` object? Is it serialized? Does it take up memory until the job is finished or dropped?

Any insights would be appreciated. Let me know if you need more code.

Comment: Normally it would serialize the object in redis as a byte-array but if you're using a mailer I think it has to respond to methods of global ID so it can be dumped and looked up using a string value.

Comment: But wouldn't the mocked object global id show up in the Job arguments in that case?

Comment: The mocked object doesn’t respond to global ID methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR The mocked object isn't stored. The only thing that sidekiq stores are what you've printed out as "Retrying Job info:".

**The long version... how does that work?**

ActiveJob enqueues each job in sidekiq with a job name and arguments. If the job fails, it serializes the (original) jobs information so the failed job can be retried. You can see the job class name and arguments in the retry job info:

```
Job: ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob
Arguments: "UserMailer", "about_to_expire_card_reminder", "deliver_now", {"params"=>{"user"=>{"_aj_globalid"=>"gid://database/User/1"}, "to"=>info@testemail.com", "email_preview"=>true, "aj_symbol_keys"=>["user,"to","email_preview"]}, "args"=>[],"_aj_symbol_keys"=>["params","args"]}
```

along with other information sidekiq needs (the queue it should be run on and the retry count).

When sidekiq runs the job, it `constantizes` the job class and calls perform on an instance of it, passing in the arguments it stored. In this case, it calls [MailDeliveryJob#perform](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/ActionMailer/MailDeliveryJob#perform-instance_method) like so:

```
ActionMailer::MailDeliveryJob.new.perform("UserMailer", "about_to_expire_card_reminder", "deliver_now", {"params"=>{"user"=>{"_aj_globalid"=>"gid://database/User/1"}, "to"=>info@testemail.com", "email_preview"=>true, "aj_symbol_keys"=>["user,"to","email_preview"]}, "args"=>[],"_aj_symbol_keys"=>["params","args"]})
```

The Activejob base class does processing on the job arguments (turning `{"_aj_globalid"=>"gid://database/User/1"}` into `User.find(1)`), then the `MailDeliveryJob#perform` method calls your mailer class like so:

```
UserMailer.with({"user"=> User.find(1), "to"=>info@testemail.com", "email_preview"=>true}).about_to_expire_card_reminder.deliver_now
```

These are the same params stored in sidekiq, except the user has been inflated. At this point the `about_to_expire_card_reminder` method creates a new mock credit card object, stores it in an instance variable on your mailer class, and the mail object gets built with access to those instance variables.

Let me know if that makes sense / if that answers the question.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It makes mucho more sense now.